# Media url from cms page of M2

Tags: magento2

I magento 1x i can put url of images like {{media }} or {{skin }}. I have take a look in frontend dev docs but not mention about this. Can anyone tell me how to put images url in cms page
many thanks

Comment: You can get refrence from here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/84582/magento2-how-can-i-call-my-theme-images-in-static-block/84603#84603

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Magento 2 has many directives such as:

## View URL

```
<img src="{{view url=images/logo.svg}}" alt="" />`
```

## Media URL

```
<img src="{{media url=test/logo.svg}}" alt="" />
```

## Example output

```
<img alt="" src="http://mag2.com/pub/media/test/logo.svg">
```

## More Info

For a complete course of directives [click here](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-what-about-directive-view-media-and-store)

Comment: If your output shows /pub/ means you didn't setup the correct folder for the magento installation (which should be /pub).

Answer (score 2):

It is the same deal.

```
<img src="{{media url=""}}" alt="" />
```

If you show/hide editor when editing the content of a cms page you can insert an image using the wysiwig.

Comment: How to use media folder in custom theme? If i want use images from 
app\design\frontend\VendorName\ThemeName\media

Comment: M2 don't have skin. Does any ways to use getSkinUrl like M1x older ver