# Magento2 : how can I call my theme images in static block

Tags: magento2, admin, theme, magento-2.0, static-block

I have install Magento2 and create static block how can I call my theme images in static block ? In Magento1.x we used **`{{skin url="images/demo.jpg"}}`**.

Any one have idea for how to call images in Static block not using editor like **`{{media url="wysiwyg/demo.jpg"}}`**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can call theme images from static block like this in magento2 :

```
<img src="{{view url="images/demo.jpg"}}" alt=""/>
```