# How to get the pub/media Url in Email Templates Magento2

Tags: magento2, template, email

Can anyone help me how to include Pub/medial url in email templates in magento2.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use below code:

```
<img src="{{media url=test/logo.svg}}" alt="" />
```

Comment: Is there any way where i can attach my order id in this like
 <a href="{{media url="'{{var order.increment_id}}'.pdf"}}" download>Please download PDF</a>
but it didnt worked plz help  me to get order id in media link ;)

Answer (score 1):

It should be the same as CMS block logic

So something like this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/94907/70343

But you can also add from extension.  That might be a cleaner option? Something like this

`Package/Modulename/view/frontend/web/images/customimg.png`

`<img src="{{view url='Package_Modulename/images/customimg.png'}}" height="30" width="30" alt="{{trans 'Custom image'}}" />`

Answer (score 1):

> You can pass Url in **`setTemplateVars()`** like below,

```
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory
){
    $this->directory = $directory;
}
```

> You can get Media Url from below code,

```
$imageUrl  =  $this->directory->getPath('media');
```

> Than after, you can pass in **`setTemplateVars()`** like shown below

```
$templateVars = array(
                        'imageUrl'   => $imageUrl
                    );
```

> You can use in your template file like this

```
{{var imageUrl}}
```

**Hope it helps.**